# deploy a django app from localhost app to web application

Tags: python, django, deployment, window, windows-server-2012

i have a little experience in django applications but only all applications it was localhost, Now i would like to know step by step how to deploy a django localhost app to web application using `www` and `donain name` to be accessible to everyone.

i have no idea how this can be done and i haven't found any guide for this task .

only where I know is :

1. I need static ip(?)
2. Buy domain name.

   3.settings.py `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['static ip','www.name.com']`

I use windows os (or I can use windows server for application) in my machine where I want to have this app.

any idea ?thank you

Comment: I would recommend you get a server on a cheap site. From there, the site will offer you instructions. Personally, I recommend Digital Ocean and Apache2 if you're tight on cash and just looking to practice or what not. Otherwise, you should probably go with somewhere a bit higher end. DM me if you need assistance.

Comment: I suggest you to use heroku first. You can refer medium posts or heroku docs to learn how to deploy in heroku. Don't buy domain name or hosting before hand. Heroku has a free structure you can use. Once you did that successfully, then go for buying a domain name and hosting site like Digital Ocean. Or You can use Google Cloud to get free hosting service for some time.

Answer (score 0):

You have some basic ideas on some of the steps, but I may not be able to mention all the steps out  to answer this question, but this is a reference to an ideal guide:
[Deployment Guide Link](http://rahmonov.me/posts/deploy-a-django-app-to-digitalocean/)